# Java static reference variable invoking non-static methods

Tags: java, object, reference, static, static-methods

```
class A{
    void display(){
      System.out.println("hai");
      }
}
class B {
    static A a;
}
class C{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
      B.a.display();
      // no compile- time error here.why?
    }
}
```

Also I know that **a** will be set to **null** during runtime. But shouldnt the compiler know
that we are accessing a non-static method
via a static reference variable?
This gives a **null pointer exception** when executed but why is the compiler not giving an 
error.

Does this mean a static reference variable behaves exactly like an object reference and thus can invoke any method(static and non-static) of the class?

Edit: I am basically confused with static field's access rules.
By definition static fields can only directly access other static fields.
So does this not include **"invoking"** a method using a static reference variable?
And display() is accessed before its object is created. Is this valid?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If `a` references an instance of `A`, why shouldn't you be able to call an instance method?

Comment: When in separate classes, this will work (why not? ). But when these classes are subclasses (non-static subclasses), you wouldn't be able to declare a static variable in the non-static class in the first place. My guese is that this mechanism is confusing you atm?

Comment: So static reference variables can "invoke" any method. They only cant directly "access" non-static right? I assumed we cant invoke non-static methods as the variable is static.

Comment: No, a static variable (reference) could invoke any member of the class.  It's just a normal reference, like any other reference.  So an example for us so we can see what it is you are talking about.

Comment: There's a couple of things you might be confused over.  *Local variables* have to be definitely initialized, and the compiler can tell if they've been initialized because they're local.  You'll get a compiler error if you try to use a local variable that hasn't been initialized yet.  The other is referring to an instance member directly (not through a reference) from a static method (or other static context).  Those are also definitely errors, and the compiler will flag them.

Answer (score 1):

"You keep using that word.  I do not think it means what you think it means."

The `static A a;` in your code says, "`a` is a (reference to) an object of type `A` that is shared across all instances of class `B`.  `a` is uninitialized.".

The compiler will have no context to determine when you are going to call the static `main()` method of class `C`, so it can't tell what the state of variable `a` will be at the time you call `C.main();`.  In fact, you could just as easily have a class D:

```
class D
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        B.a = new A();
        C.main( args );
    }
}
```

which would make the code above completely valid and runnable.

Comment: Yes I added the **extends A** by mistake . Corrected my question